# Xamarin.Forms save user in Shared Functions

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I saved a token in the mobile with SharedFunctions interface i created
In IOS:

```
public void SaveAccessToken(string token)
{
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(token, "AccessToken");
}
```

In Android:

```
public void SaveAccessToken(string token)
{
    var mSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(Android.App.Application.Context);
    var mPrefsEditor = mSharedPrefs.Edit();

    mPrefsEditor.PutString("AccessToken", token);
    mPrefsEditor.Commit();
    mPrefsEditor.Dispose();
    mSharedPrefs.Dispose();
}
```

I also want to save a object instead of a string.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i save string in my example. But in other function i want to save object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look at [the documentation of NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414067-setobject?language=objc), it seems as if writing an object is somewhat restricted, hence I'd suggest you to go another way: Serialize the object using Newtonsoft.JSON (or another JSON library) and write the serialized object.

For iOS:

```cs
public void SaveAccessToken<T>(string key, T value)
{
    var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(serializedObject, key);
}
```

and similarly for Android

```cs
public void SaveAccessToken<T>(string key, T value)
{
    var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);

    var mSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(Android.App.Application.Context);
    var mPrefsEditor = mSharedPrefs.Edit();

    mPrefsEditor.PutString(serializedObject, key);
    mPrefsEditor.Commit();
    mPrefsEditor.Dispose();
    mSharedPrefs.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)